# go grpc server doesn't known client ungraceful dead

Tags: go, grpc

I am using go-grpc to create a bidirectional stream. When I unplug the cable, the server doesn't known client is dead for a very very long time. How can I detect client is gone in this case ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `GRPC` server-side handler will know about client context cancellation the next time it will try to `Send`/`Recv` message to/from stream: the error will be returned:

```
func (s *server) handler(stream your_service.Stream) error {
    if err := stream.Recv(); err != nil {
        // you will have context cancelation error here
    }
}
```

In some cases it may be useful to check context cancellation explicitly:

```
func (s *server) handler(stream your_service.Stream) error {
     // some logic
     select {
         case <-stream.Context().Done():
             return stream.Context().Err()
         default:
     }
}
```

By the way, do you unplug the cable literally? Because it may be treated in different ways by the operational system. Why don't you use any modern virtualization tools, like Docker, for your tests?

Comment: In my case, I cann't use `stream.Recv()` to detect. I did use the second way, watch the stream.Context().Done(), but it took a very very long time to notice client is gone. I'm going to implement my own heartbeat to make it work.

Comment: By the way, yes, i unplug the cable literally! Thanks for your tips, really help a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem as you did. In my case, when I used Ctrl-C to terminate my test client, the server detected it pretty quickly, but when I used Ctrl-Z (or if I cut power to my micro-controller) the server would take forever to close the hanging connection. You need to use some sort of heartbeat to check on the connection using something like gRPC's keepAlive feature. I had to create my own heartbeat message that I sent periodically because of a problem with using gRPC behind Envoy (https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/2086)